# JetBrains Space Deploy to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, jetbrains-space-automation

We are experimenting with Jetbrains Space as our code repo and CI/CD. We are trying to find a way to setup the `.space.kts` file to deploy to AWS Lambda.

We want the `develop` branch to publish to the Lambda `$Latest` and when we merge to the `main` branch from the `develop` branch we want it to publish a new Lambda version and link that version to the alias `pro`.

I've looked around but haven't found anything that would suggest there is a pre-built solution for controlling AWS Lambda so my current thinking is something like this:

```
job("Publish to Lambda Latest") {

    startOn {
        gitPush {
            branchFilter {
                +"refs/heads/develop"
            }
        }
    }

    container(displayName = "AWS Lambda CLI", image = "amazon/aws-cli") {
        
        // Space Packages repository
        env["REPOSITORY_URL"] = "https://..."

        shellScript {
            content = """
                echo Deploying to Lambda Latest...
                ...
            """
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not convinced that using a shell script is a very robust way to do this as I will need to pass variables from one command to another. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to use the AWS SDK as a dependency of your `.space.kts`, and use it in a `kotlinScript` block instead of `shellScript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in DSL for interacting with AWS.

If you want a solution that is more type-safe than plain `shellScript`, and maybe reuse data between multiple calls etc, you can still use Kotlin code directly (in a `kotlinScript` block instead of `shellScript`).

You [can specify maven dependencies for your `.space.kts` script](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/space/run-kotlin-code.html#using-external-packages-in-kotlinscript) via the `@DependsOn` annotation, which you can use for instance to add modules from the AWS Java SDK:

```kotlin
// you can add other module artifacts like "s3", "ec2", etc.
@file:DependsOn("software.amazon.awssdk:lambda:2.13.7")

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.*
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.lambda.model.*

job("Publish to Lambda Latest") {

    startOn {
        gitPush {
            branchFilter {
                +"refs/heads/develop"
            }
        }
    }

    container(displayName = "AWS Lambda", image = "openjdk:11") {

        kotlinScript { spaceApi ->
            // use AWS SDK classes here, for instance:
            val client = LambdaClient.builder().build()
            val updateFunctionCodeRequest = UpdateFunctionCodeRequest.builder()
                .functionName("name")
                .s3Bucket("bucket")
                .s3Key("key")
                .publish(true)
                .build()
            client.updateFunctionCode(updateFunctionCodeRequest)
            client.close()
        }
    }
}
```

The piece of code shown here is just for the sake of the example (to show that you can use the AWS SDK classes and methods), it's not a complete example on how to publish a lambda.

Comment: any insight into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064389/jetbrains-intellij-kotlin-filedependson ?